# New SharePoint online - Checked out pop up message

Tags: sharepoint-online, popup

We are now seeing the Red Checked out arrow on items (only when it isn't selected) when you hover over the icon a pop up appears that gives you an option to Check in or Discard Check out if it is checked out to you - otherwise it tells you who has the document checked out.

In some libraries we are not seeing the Check in or Discard Check out info in the Pop up message - what settings in the library may be causing this??